# why is my cron job not executing properly?

Tags: bash, macos, unix

I have a shell script written like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd Documents/Hi_tech_team_10/
chmod +x /Users/twoodwa/Documents/Hi_tech_team_10/test.rb
ruby test.rb
```

when i execute it in the terminal it works perfectly, but when i set it as a cron job by doing

```
crontab -e
```

then editing and saving the file with

```
*/10 * * * * /Users/twoodwa/Documents/Hi_tech_team_10/test.sh
```

the script either doesn't execute, or it is doing something different than just running it like it does from the terminal.

what is the issue?

EDIT: i have changed the script to use absolute paths as so, still not working :

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod +x /Users/twoodwa/Documents/Hi_tech_team_10/test.rb
ruby /Users/twoodwa/Documents/Hi_tech_team_10/test.rb
```

Comment: cd Documents only works if you run the script in the directory just above Documents.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: On Mac OS you should generally use launchd rather than cron, although creating a launchd plist is more complicated than a cron job.

Comment: @Barmar i will use that if i have to, but i would rather understand why cron job is not working properly

Comment: You don't need `chmod +x test.rb`.

Comment: You do need `chmod +x test.sh` though

Comment: First off, `chmod +x` is not something you need to do if you aren't running the file as an executable. Second, why can't you just call ruby directly from the cron tab?

Comment: check this link [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working). Also, please check the erorrs/issues while executing from `cron` by using like :`*/10 * * * * /Users/twoodwa/Documents/Hi_tech_team_10/test.sh > /Users/twoodwa/Documents/Hi_tech_team_10/err.log 2>&1`...this might help

Answer (score 1):

First checkpoint: if script is executable

Second checkpoint: you should use absolute paths

Third checkpoint: never trust environment. Cron has it's own environment (true, suggested in comments)

Good idea: Addding some logging to a terminal/file to check execution and when it had failed.

Comment: the script works perfectly when ran in the terminal like so: `sh /Users/twoodwa/Documents/Hi_tech_team_10/test.sh` so I think it should be doing the same thing with the cron job correct?

Comment: @TraversWoodward cron jobs don't execute your .profile or .bashrc, so if the script depends on anything there it won't work from cron.

Comment: Add `>~/cron.out 2>&1` to the end of the cron job, so that error messages will be put in your `~/cron.out` file.

Comment: @Barmar so you're saying because the script is in a directory on my user profile it won't work? If thats the case will moving test.rb and test.sh to another directory fix the issue?

Comment: @TraversWoodward I never said anything about a directory. If the ruby script depends on environment variables that you set in your shell startup scripts, it won't work because they won't be set when you run the cron job.

Comment: Is ruby in the cron $PATH?

Answer (score -3):

The issue is in crontab, change crontab to pointing to test.rb

Comment: No, he wants to run the shell script that runs test.rb.